# Non-reproducible results in pytorch after saving and loading the model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am unable to reproduce my results in PyTorch after saving and loading the model whereas the in-memory model works as expected. Just for context, I am seeding my libraries, using model.eval to turn off the dropouts but still, results are not reproducible. Any suggestions if I am missing something.  Thanks in advance.

Libraries that I am using:-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import numpy as np
import random
```

Libraries that I am seeding

```
manualSeed = 1
np.random.seed(manualSeed)
random.seed(manualSeed)
torch.manual_seed(manualSeed)
random.seed(manualSeed)
```

Below are the results on in memory and loaded model.

```
In Memory model Loss : 1.596395881312668, In Memory model Accuracy : tensor(0.3989)
Loaded model Loss : 1.597083057567572, Loaded model Accuracy : tensor(0.3983)
```

Comment: please post some more context or a code example, details on the model and the difference with the memory model.

Comment: @amdex I have added small code and my results. Please let me know if I should make it more informative. Thanks.

Comment: If you could add the model definition and whether you run it on GPU or not would be great. That is also relevant to help you out

Answer (score 2):

Since the date that Szymon Maszke posted his response above (2019), a new API has been added, [torch.use_deterministic_algorithms()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.use_deterministic_algorithms.html).

This new function does everything that `torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic` did (namely, makes CuDNN convolution operations deterministic), plus much more (makes every known normally-nondeterministic function either deterministic or throw an error if a deterministic implementation is not available). CuDNN convolution is only one of the many possible sources of nondeterminism in PyTorch, so `torch.use_deterministic_algorithms()` should now be used instead of the old `torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic`.

The link to the [reproducibility documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) is still relevant. However, note that this page has been changed a fair bit since 2019.

Answer (score 1):

## On non-reproducibility

Values are pretty close, so it's not like those are not being reproducible, error margin is quite large.

From [documentation on reproducibility](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html):

> There are some PyTorch functions that use CUDA functions that can be a
>   source of non-determinism. One class of such CUDA functions are atomic
>   operations, in particular atomicAdd, where the order of parallel
>   additions to the same value is undetermined and, for floating-point
>   variables, a source of variance in the result.

The more complicated the model, the more chance of random variance based on functions using `atomicAdd` by pure coincidence, essentially there is some inherent variation you won't win against.

## Improve reproducibility on CUDA

I suppose you are running your inference on GPU, you should use those two functions as well:

```
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
```

Remember to seed both the same way before inference, you should see results being much closer to each other.